# Auto save parking location on phone

Tags: android, gps-tracking

I'm looking for an android app to save car's parking location.

All apps I've found so far requires user action for that (open app - save as parking location)

I'm looking for an app which saves location whenever specific Bluetooth device (car audio) is disconnected.